# Read banned words from a text file

Tags: c#, text-files, bots

I am currently trying to build a moderator-bot that automatically scans a chat for banned words and then times people out when saying them.

Currently I have those banned words in a string-list but I'd want the bot to actually take the words out of a `.txt` file so I can easily have a bigger list of words without having to write a huge part of the code only containing bad words.

Currently my (part of the) code that does this looks like this:

```
List<string> BannedWords = new List<string> { "dog", "kitten", "bird" };

private bool BannedWordFilter(string username, string message)
{
    foreach(string word in BannedWords)
    {
        if (message.Contains(word))
        {
            string command = "/timeout " + username + " 10";
            irc.sendChatMessage(command);
            irc.sendChatMessage(username + "no banned words allowed!");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So for now the bot times out people saying the words I put up as test. 
But I am not really sure how I could built it so that the bot takes words out of a `.txt` file.

Comment: `BannedWords = FileReadAllLines("banned.txt").ToList();`

Answer (score 4):

If you have a text with one banned word per line, e.g. like this:

```
dog
kitten
bird
```

...then you can read it using

```
BannedWords = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("bannedWords.txt")`;
```

This returns an array of strings, each containing a line of the text file. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

BTW: if you have lots of banned words, then it might be better to put then into a lookup, as this will make the lookup faster, e.g:

```
// read banned words
private ILookup<string, string> BannedWords;
// ...
BannedWords = File.ReadAllLines("bannedWords.txt").ToLookup(w => w);

// check message for banned words
if (message.Split(' ').Any(w => bannedWords.Contains(w)) 
{
    // message contains a banned word
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much as well. Unfortunately if i try to insert those lines it produces quite some errors. Like that i need 2 elements in ILookup <TKey , TElement> ?

Comment: @scitch Should be `private ILookup<string, string> BannedWords`

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
var wordsFile = File.ReadAllLines(BANNEDWORDS_PATH);
List<string> BannedWords = new List<string>(wordsFile);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. 
But if i try to use it it says "The modifier readonly is not valid for this item" :(